# Average road distance for each county between two location/Lat-Long

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, r, google-maps

Say, one travels from Times Square (1451 Broadway New York, NY, 10036) to White House (1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500). For this 4+ hour drive, I would like to calculate the average road distance that needs to be driven in each COUNTY along the way.

Note:

- A road can cross the same state or same county couple or more times
- We can consider the default recommended road provided by Google maps API

I would like to have a recommendation on the approach to calculate the average distance in each county.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the geometry of the road route, it's a very simple query:

```
WITH route AS (
  SELECT ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING(...)',4326) AS geom
)
SELECT 
  county.name, 
  ST_Length(ST_Intersection(
    ST_Transform(county.geom, 2163), 
    ST_Transform(route.geom, 2163))) AS distance
FROM county
JOIN route
ON ST_Intersects(county.geom, route.geom)
```

The solution assumes both route and county are stored using an SRID of 4326, but it calculates the distance value in the US Atlas projection, which is hopefully accurate enough for your purposes. You reference an "average" road distance, which presumes multiple routes, which isn't quite what your example provides. Basically for one route, there will be one distance for each county intersecting the route.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. You are right, for one route there will be one distance for each county intersection. For the county information will Google's fusion table be a good choice? https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1xdysxZ94uUFIit9eXmnw1fYc6VcQiXhceFd_CVKa#map:id=2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an R approach.

Example data:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
b <- as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialLines')
projection(b) <- projection(p)
p <- spTransform(p, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84'))
b <- spTransform(b, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84'))
```

Solution:

```
i <- intersect(b, p)
g <- gLength(i, byid=T)
data.frame(i$NAME_2, length=g)
```